How do I set a variable to ActiveCell.Row
I would like to be able to return the row number of the active cell then assign that value a variable. It is saying "Object not Defined" for ActiveCell.Row when I attempt to run the Macro. I would like to have cells copied to another sheet based on the value of the active row.
This is the erroneous code
Sub CopyPaste()
Set CurrentRow = ActiveCell.Row
Select Case test_expression

Case CurrentRow = 2
Sheets("Drop-In").Range("A2").EntireRow.Copy Sheets("CompletedV2").Range("A2")

Case Else
MsgBox "This is a sample box"

End Select
End Sub


Set is for objects. For variables for values do not use it.

You have some problems with the Select Case loop also. Pls. have a look in Excel Help for Select Case article, where you find a good example how to use it.

Copy Entire Row If String in Column Matches



Here is a simple scenario that might get you on your feet.
To keep things relatively safe, I've implemented a few restrictions that unfortunately complicated the code. Best, create a copy of your workbook and try the code there. Don't forget to close the original.
If the value in column A of the active cell's row is Test, it copies the entire (active cell's) row to the first available cell in column A of the destination sheet. Otherwise, it displays a message explaining why it 'failed'. In a nutshell, if you have selected a row where the cell in column A is equal to Test, the row will be copied.
To get an accurate answer, you need to explain what you're trying to do in more detail e.g. as I did above. Edit your post (question) adding more information. If my code is close, you could paste it into another question and explain what it does, what it should do, and what you have tried to achieve the desired functionality.

Option Explicit

Sub CopyIfMatch()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const SRC_SHEET_NAME As String = "Drop-In"
    Const DST_SHEET_NAME As String = "CompletedV2"
    Const TEST_STRING As String = "Test" ' the string to match
    
    ' Source
    
    Dim scell As Range: Set scell = ActiveCell
    If scell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no active cell
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = scell.Worksheet
    
    If StrComp(sws.Name, SRC_SHEET_NAME, vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then ' (A=a)
        MsgBox "This only works for sheet """ & SRC_SHEET_NAME & """!", _
            vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim SourceString As String: ' the value in column 'A' of the active row
    SourceString = CStr(scell.EntireRow.Columns("A").Value)
    
    If SourceString <> TEST_STRING Then ' is equal (case-sensitive i.e. 'a<>A')
        MsgBox "The Source string """ & SourceString _
            & """ is different than the Test string """ & TEST_STRING & """!", _
            vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Destination (different sheet but same workbook as source)
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = sws.Parent.Sheets(DST_SHEET_NAME)
    Dim dcell As Range: ' first 'available' cell in column 'A'
    Set dcell = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    ' Caution, the previous doesn't work if column 'A' in source could be empty!
    ' Keep in mind that you can copy entire rows only to column 'A'!
   
    ' Copy
    scell.EntireRow.Copy dcell

    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Matching source row " & scell.Row _
        & " copied to destination row " & dcell.Row & ".", vbInformation

End Sub


This will assign the active row to the CurrentRow variable.
If the CurrentRow is two it will paste that into row 2 on the second sheet.
If it's between 3 and 5 it will paste it into the relevant row.
Not sure why you're using the Select Case statement though.
Public Sub CopyPaste()

    Dim CurrentRow As Long
    CurrentRow = ActiveCell.Row
    
    Select Case CurrentRow
        Case 2
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Drop-In").Rows(CurrentRow).Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CompletedV2").Rows(2)
        Case 3 To 5
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Drop-In").Rows(CurrentRow).Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CompletedV2").Rows(CurrentRow)
        Case Else
            MsgBox "This is a sample box", vbInformation + vbOKOnly
    End Select

End Sub

